# Have "Title" link to the file

Tags: 2013

SP 2013.
SharePoint Designer access.
No PS admin access.

I want a user to be able to click on the Title and it opens the file in the web browser (or default behavior) which is currently what happens when they click the file name.

I am using a document library with doc/docx files in it.  The file names are horrendous and the titles are accurate and concise.

I used SharePointDesigner to change the aspx code by adding variations the below code.

```
`<FieldRef Name="Title" linkToItem="TRUE" linkToItemAllowed="ALLOWED" listItemMenu="TRUE"/>`
```

I attempted `linkToFile="TRUE"` as well and it worked but it glitched out the view and removed the icons for some reason.  I reverted and tried again but no the linkage to the file was gone.

Currently when I use `linkToItem="TRUE"` clicking on the Title takes me to some sort of column metadata editing page where I can change the column info for the current item.

[image: picture of the editing page]

I think this sums it up. Hopefully everyone is able to understand me.
Thanks.